# Firebird, group by foreign key field

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

1. **PEOPLE**:

   ```
   INDEX, NAME, SURNAME
   ```
2. **ACTIVITY**:

   ```
   INDEX, ACTIVITY, PEOPLE_INDEX
   ```

I want to display:

```
select PEOPLE_INDEX, count(INDEX) from ACTIVITY group by PEOPLE_INDEX
```

but instead of 'PEOPLE_INDEX' I want to see NAME and SURNAME from 'PEOPLE' table.

How should I write my query?

Thank you!

Comment: The index column in Count function, from which table is it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.NAME, P.SURNAME, A.PEOPLE_INDEX, COUNT(A.INDEX) AS Cnt
FROM ACTIVITY A INNER JOIN PEOPLE P
ON A.INDEX = P.INDEX
GROUP BY P.NAME, P.SURNAME, A.PEOPLE_INDEX
```